# Find a file by name in Visual Studio Code

Tags: file, search, visual-studio-code, find

How can I *find a file by name (or path)* in Visual Studio Code?

A Visual Studio shortcut I'm used to is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, but it does not work here.

Comment: In Visual studio the shortcut is `[CTRL] + ';'` instead

Comment: Something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095376/how-do-i-search-for-files-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: It's Ctr+P. Not Ctr+,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I search for files in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095376/how-do-i-search-for-files-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @AnandRaja I had the same discussion some time ago, maybe a year. This question is asking specifically for `Find file by name` functionality from Visual Studio. Question you suggested is more broad. Think also about search-ability, Lot of people search for this.

Comment: @AnandRaja Regarding `Ctrl+P` - I am using En-US default configuration for Visual Studio and `Ctrl+P` for me brings Print Dialog. On the other hand `Ctrl+,` brings "omni box". One that finds files, sybols, etc...

Comment: @Nenad may be, it may differ depending on the region(geo location). My keyboard is also US based, but geo location is India.

Comment: @AnandRaja Yes, that could be the reason. Probably `EN-IN` culture in Windows, instead of `EN-US`?

Comment: you can make it with `Explorer Tree` https://stackoverflow.com/a/61460276/2736742

Answer (score 721, accepted):

When you have opened a folder in a workspace you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac) and start typing the filename, or extension to filter the list of filenames

if you have:

- plugin.ts
- page.css
- plugger.ts

You can type `css` and press enter and it will open the `page.css`. If you type `.ts` the list is filtered and contains two items.

Comment: If you want to change the shortcut, look for `Go to file...` in File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: {
  "key": "cmd+p",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInFilePicker",
  "when": "inFilesPicker && inQuickOpen"
}

Comment: We should notice that `Ctrl+P` opens file in Preview mode. In order to open file in new tab, let's follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/43707807/190309

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, only already open files show up when searching (they can still be found after closing, but never opened files does not show).

Comment: That is. Additionally you can run Ctrl+K+S to search all shortcuts

Comment: anyone knows why it is the letter "P" ? knowing what it stands for helps remembering

Comment: @Zitrax is right: Ctrl+P [filename] does not work on all files in the Explorer, it only lists files that are already open -- at least when one is using a remote back-end like WSL, etc.  The explorer needs a real search tool which works under all conditions.

Answer (score 43):

Press `Ctl+T` will open a search box. Delete # symbol and enter your file name.

Comment: This is just a longer way around to arrive to exactly the same point as pressing directly `Ctrl + P`.

Comment: It's a shame this does not get more upvotes; this is solving the OP's question, whereas the answer by @Dick both finds the file _and_ opens it, which was not the OP's request.

Answer (score 31):

It is CMD + P (or CTRL + P) by default. However the keyboard bindings may differ according to your preferences.

To know your bindings go to the "Keyboard Shortcuts" settings and search for "Go to File"

Answer (score 24):

I believe the action name is "workbench.action.quickOpen".

Comment: Useful for anyone not using the default keymap (e.g. those using the emacs keymap).

Comment: @ijoseph or the Intellij keymap

Answer (score 15):

You can find all files by name using the 'Search: find in files' function.
This method is helpfull when you want get a **list of files** that is persisted in search dialog.

1. start 'Search: find all files' (default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
2. In the dialog, turn on *'regex'*. (the <kbd>.*</kbd> in the search bar.)
3. search for: `^(?<!\n)`.  This regex matches the first line of each file
4. Add (part of) the filename in 'files to include'. note that this fields support wildcards.
5. Outputs a list filenames.

### Example

To find all `tsconfig.json` files, including variants like `tsconfig.node.json`
use the searchterm **`tsconfig*.json`**
[image: find all tsconfig files]
you can now click through the results to open each file.

Answer (score 3):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on mac.
You can see it if you close all tabs

Comment: By default `Ctrl+Shift+O` is "Go to symbol..." binding. Lists all symbols on the currently open page.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the actual configuration can be different as a result of various extensions, it doesn't seem helpful to give a specific shortcut as answer. While the default shortcut seems to be `Cmd + P` (on a Mac), you can find out or reconfigure it when navigating to your `Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts` and search for `Go to File...`

[image: Picture of keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio Code, filtered by the command 'go to file']

In my case, the [IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings) added the double-shift shortcut which I'm using a lot, coming from a Jetbrains IDE.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Github page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/152481), it's now a simple `Cmd+F` inside the File Explorer tree on Mac (and presumably `Ctrl+F` on Windows). Found and highlighted all the `README.md` files I've been working on:

file search results in vscode file explorer pane

[image: 2]

> **Caveat**: The tree has to be fully expanded for this to work.

Comment: This is filtering functionality in the File Explorer tree. If your file is not already visible (in expanded directory node), it will not show up. In fact, directory containing the file you are looking for, if collapsed, will disappear when you activate the filter (click on the filter icon).

Comment: Yes, the unfortunate prerequisite is that the tree has to be fully expanded. Added that caveat.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer for the question. This is much longer and more complicated way to find a file. It's not practical.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm upvoting this, this is the only answer that helped me after much searching (wondering why the previous "type to filter" functionality was no longer working). In a very large repo and/or certain situations, this is a necessary feature and much more useful than cmd+p. The fact that folders must be expanded is a very annoying drawback, but is not the fault of this poster. And fortunately, they are working on fixing it here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66971