# How can I open a file in a new tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I open a new file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, so it doesn't override the current file, but rather use a new tab?

Also, would it be possible to focus the searched file instead of opening it, if it was already opened on a tab, to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to config vscode to open files always in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713405/how-to-config-vscode-to-open-files-always-in-a-new-tab)

Answer (score 277, accepted):

When a single click to a file is made in the sidebar, Visual Studio Code opens it in **Preview Mode**, which allows you to quickly view files.

#### Behavior of Preview Mode

- The tabs in the Preview Mode are not kept open.
- As soon as you open another file from the sidebar, it overrides the existing file if it's in preview mode.
- The title of the tab will be in italic if it's in preview mode, just like the below screenshot.

[image: To open a file for editing (i.e. don't open in Preview Mode), double-click on the file in the sidebar.]

> #### **Important!**
>
> If you want to edit a file, don't open in Preview Mode, double-click on the file in the sidebar instead.

If the file is already open in Preview mode, then to convert it to edit mode:

- double click on its italic file name in the title bar, *or*
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Steps to Disable Preview Mode

**Criteria:**

If you want to disable Preview Mode all together, that is:

- accessing file through side-menu.
- opening quick open menu using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

**Solution:**

- Open the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_command-palette) using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
- Type `Preferences: Open User Settings`. This will open the Settings editor. Search for `workbench.editor.enablePreview`, and uncheck the checkbox (changes are autosaved and indicated with a blue left border).

**Additional:**

- If you only want to disable preview mode in the quick open menu, uncheck the box for `workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen`.

Comment: If you want to keep the standard preview behaviour, you can open a file in preview mode using `ctrl+p` and then open it fully for editing using `ctrl+k enter`. This turns the preview tab into a fully independent tab as you'd get if you opened the file by double-clicking it in the explorer.

Comment: "double click on the file in sidebar" also works for tab titile bar, if tab title bar is italic then double click on it removes preview mode

Answer (score 28):

TL;DR for Mac users

**Step 1:** Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

**Step 2:** Search for `Preview` and disable `Workbench › Editor: Enable Preview`

[image: Search for Preview and disable Workbench › Editor: Enable Preview]

Answer (score 6):

For both to keep a file tab open when you first click and after use, go to the definition,

> "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false

It is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing a setting, a simpler option is to drag the file from the sidebar on to the tabs bar. It opens in a new tab.

Comment: It's easier to double click it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → search for *"settings.json"*, and at the last line before `}`, add a comma to the last option and paste:

`"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false`

For example:

```
{
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Consolas', 'monospace', 'Times New Roman'",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "monospace",
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the quick open menu, a file can be opened in the background by pressing the right arrow key. The current tab, with the quick open menu remains in the foreground, and the same process can be repeated to open multiple files.

VSCode doc can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_open-multiple-files-from-quick-open).