# How to search specific filename in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, ide

For example, I want to search a file whose name is "module-product.js" to rename it.

But there are lots of files whose names started with "module-".

How to quickly find the specific file in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: ...You hit `Ctrl-P` (or `Command-P` on a Mac) and start typing `product.js`?

Comment: Hi @ChatterOne, the method works! Could you add the answer below? I'll choose it as the useful answer. Thank you.

Comment: Duplicated question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648566/how-can-i-find-file-by-name-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and enter details into the popup that you would like to search for! You can prefix the search with `#` to search for a function.

Others (on a mac) include;

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> Show all Symbols
- <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> Go to Line...
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> Go to File...
- <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Go to Symbol...

Answer (score 2):

A secret feature of VSCode is the [explorer filter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_advanced-tree-navigation).

Cmd-Shift-E (or clicking the sidebar) focusses the explorer.  Typing some characters shows only files or directories whose names contain the given characters.  Esc clears the search.

As usual, you can use Up- and Down-Arrow to navigate the displayed file list and Cmd-Down to open the currently highlighted file.