# Find a file by name with regex in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to search for a file name in VSCode, and I'd like to be able to use Regex to filter the search results.

I've already seen answers like this [Find a file by name in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648566/find-a-file-by-name-in-visual-studio-code) but unfortunately there's no obvious way to apply regex.

The search function has regex support, but only seems to look inside files, and not at the file names themselves. And there doesn't seem to be anything in settings that you can change that would support regex file searching, just including/excluding things like .gitignore.

Is there a way to search files by regex in VSCode? Do I need another tool?

Comment: For anyone else who wants a solution to this, I created a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127723).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the same, but "[Open Multiple Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-open-multiple-files)" extension from Fabio Spampinato makes you open all the files corresponding to a certain glob (which basically is regex for files).

Comment: @SecretAgentMan you are right, but without that extension, the answer will be invalid in any case, I only can write the extension's name in the answer.