# How can I prevent VS Code from replacing a newly opened, unmodified (preview) tab with a subsequently opened one?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.3.1 with the newly introduced tabs.

When I click on files, the first file will open in a tab. If I do not make any changes to this file, the second clicked file will open in the same tab.

How can I avoid this and make Visual Studio Code always open a new tab?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945820/vs-code-keyboard-shortcut-to-take-file-out-of-preview-mode/47840585#47840585 Alt-Enter added this functionality as of v1.19 in December 2017.

Comment: if you double click and open the file form left panel, it will not be replaced by other tabs

Comment: for those who want to open new file in the previous session (in a new tab, when VScode is off):     `"window.restoreWindows": "preserve",` https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36964

Comment: Haven't seen it mentioned, but you can also middle-click in the Explorer sidebar and that will open it in normal, non-preview mode

Answer (score 3350, accepted):

When you [single-]click a file in the left sidebar's file browser or open it from the quick open menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>, type the file name, <kbd>Enter</kbd>), Visual Studio Code opens it in what's called "Preview Mode", which allows you to quickly **view** files.

Preview Mode tabs are not kept open. As soon as you go to open another file from the sidebar, the existing Preview Mode tab (if one exists) is used. You can determine if a tab is in Preview Mode, by looking at its title in the tab bar. If the title is *italic*, the tab is in preview mode.

To open a file for editing (i.e. don't open in Preview Mode), double-click on the file in the sidebar, or single-click it in the sidebar then double click the title of its Preview Mode tab.

If you want to disable Preview Mode all together, you can do so by setting `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false` in your settings file. You can also use the `"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen"` option to disable it only from the quick open menu.

Before you can disable Preview Mode, you'll need to open your [Settings File](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace#_settings-file-locations).

**Pro Tip**: You can use the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)(shortcut Ctrl+Shift+P) to open your settings file, just enter "`Preferences: Open User Settings`"!

Once you've opened your settings file (*your* settings file should be located on the right), add the `"workbench.editor.enablePreview"` property, and set its value to `false`.

You can learn more about Visual Studio Code's "Preview Mode"  [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tabs#_preview-mode).
See also article [How to Always Open Files in a New Tab - VSCode](https://vscode.one/new-tab-vscode/)

Comment: can i change `double-click` to `ctrl+click` ?

Comment: Since I have arrived the second time within a few months at this answer, also note that there is a `Workbench > Editor: Show Tabs` setting, which, when disabled, looks similar to the preview mode, because you never see a tab appearing except the one you open.

Comment: When using `ctrl+p` to locate a file, you can also use `alt+enter` or press the right arrow key while the file is highlighted to open it in normal mode (not preview mode)

Comment: I submitted a PR to change the default behaviour https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/115088

Comment: It's not only most useless feature, it's also actually quite annoying. If I knew I would have upvoted it in the discussion thread. It's a strange criterion for a backlog candidate. I don't think regular users regularly check GitHub's issues looking for upvoting new features.

Comment: Cant you just do Ctrl + \ (Ctrl + BackSlash)?

Comment: > You can use the Command Palette(shortcut Ctrl+Shift+P) to open your settings file, just enter "`Preferences: Open User Settings`" .  
Following those instructions leads to "No matching results" if you're doing it in a Remote VSCode window.  You need to open a local window and then this works.

Comment: Never knew this existed, wow

Answer (score 223):

I came up with the same problem, and open *setting.json* file, add the following:

```json
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

Comment: Most straight to the point answer. Additionally, you can find `settings.json` by hitting shift+command+p (command palett) in macOS and entering in "settings.json".

Answer (score 211):

If you don't want to disable *preview mode* you can explicitly tell `vscode` to keep a specific tab open. As mentioned above a tab heading with italic text is in *preview mode*.

To get a tab out of *preview mode* you can either right click on the tab and choose `keep open` or use the shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> `enter` that is mapped to the command `workbench.action.keepEditor`.

Furthermore, double-clicking on a tab also gets it out of *preview mode* (verified in `vscode` 1.44.0).

Comment: For future readers its: `CMD+k` release key combo and then hit `Enter`

Answer (score 76):

## For 2020:

easy as pie, tap preferences (<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>,</kbd> on Mac),

## The secret is "Enable preview"

they added it right there:

[image]

Turn **OFF** (uncheck) for **NORMAL** behavior.

i.e., Turn **OFF** to **avoid** the "automatic closing" behavior.

Comment: this adds almost nothing on top of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45431612/11107541) from 2017.

Answer (score 50):

Use `workbench.editor.enablePreview: false` to disable Preview mode completely.

Use `workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen: false` to disable Preview mode for the files open from quick open menu.

Answer (score 39):

Open in new Tab Solution:

1. Open the command palette by: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
2. Open settings file by: *Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)*
3. Under user setting, enable Tabs by: `"workbench.editor.showTabs": true`

Comment: CMD + Shift + P opens the Command Palette now. (CTRL on Win). Ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette

Comment: `"workbench.editor.showTabs": true` worked for me

Answer (score 35):

### Watch for filenames in ***italic***

Note that, the file name on the tab is formatted in ***italic*** if it has been opened in `Preview Mode`.

### Quickly take a file out of Preview Mode

To keep the file always available in VSCode editor (that is, to take it out of `Preview Mode` into normal mode), you can **double-click** on the tab. Then, you will notice the name becomes non-italic.

Of course, you can simply double-click to open a file. This will open the file in a new tab, skipping the Preview Mode.

### Feature or bug?

I believe Preview Mode is helpful especially when you have limited screen space and need to check many files.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that you can skip preview mode in the first place by double-clicking the file as you open it.

Answer (score 26):

For anyone who don't want to disabled **Preview Mode**.

As I read whole of comments and I found what I preferred that is the shortcut key to pin the opened file from **Quick Open/Ctrl+P** or that's mean to keep the opened file to the editor, and **yes** also don't need to switch your hand to the mouse to double-click on files list.

Thanks to @jontem and @MattLBeck.

Call `save` command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> on Mac) is the easiest way to reach what I preferred.

And if you found out you do this to keep opened file to editor quite frequently, yes I preferred you should setting the option `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false` or `"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false` as others mentioned before.

Answer (score 23):

> ⚡ Actually, VSCode shows you the preview of a file.

You can disable the preview with this:

```json
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
```

⬇️ Basically just add these two settings and you're good to go.

[image: VSCode tip]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score 22):

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *User Settings*: add this line

`"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false`

Comment: what does this add on top of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46498078/11107541) from 2017?

Answer (score 18):

If you want to open a file permanently from "Go To File..." (⌘P), press "right arrow" instead of return.

This also keeps the Go To File... search bar open so you can quickly open multiple files.

Comment: Yep. Pressing "right arrow" to open in a new tab works on Windows too.

Comment: Perfect - THIS should have been the accepted answer, as it does not 'fix' the problem by disabling a useful feature, but instead answers the question by showing how Ctrl-P to open files should be used! The fact it keeps the Go To File open as well is an excellent bonus

Comment: This is no longer working, has this feature been removed? Can anyone confirm if it still works?

Answer (score 18):

This is not a new answer. It is just showing how to do it via UI.
Open settings via `File => Preference => Settings`. [The most upvoted answer is the correct choice.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38723094/3139779)

Then in search field type Preview.

After that select Workbench and look for Enable preview options.

Uncheck the boxes.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You can do it via GUI

[image]

Search for **preview**

[image]

uncheck the options `Enable Preview` and `Enable Preview from Quick Open`

Answer (score 13):

From settings you can find edit settings.json
You need to search by Preview. Please check the below screen short.

Add the below code there:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

[Image of this section](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R9PM_oNkvqzSaXIdxzIyC3ExiXhtlI-4/view?usp=sharing)

Full code given below:
{
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {

```
},

"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
```

}

Answer (score 11):

Essentially, there are three settings that one has to update (Preference >> settings):

- **workbench.editor.enablePreview:** set this to globally enable or
  disable preview editors
- **workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen:** set this to enable or
  disable preview editors when opened from Quick Open
- **workbench.editor.showTabs:** finally one will need to set this
  otherwise, there will be no tabs displayed and you will just be
  wondering why setting/unsetting the above two did not work

Answer (score 11):

### 1. Double-click your files instead of single-clicking.

- Instead of single clicking on your files, (like I do in the previous GIF) double-click. This will tell VS Code that you want the file to stay open when you switch to a new file.
- Here's my beautiful demonstration of this:

[image]

### 2. Double-click the tab you want to keep open

- This works if the tab you are working with is in "Preview Mode" (italicized) and you want it to stay open when you open another file.

[image]

### 3. Right click your tab and select "Keep Open"

- This one's self-explanatory. Simply right-click on the Preview Mode tab on the tab at the top of your screen (while it's italicized) and click on "Keep Open" once the context menu pops up.
- Here's my beautiful demonstration of this:

[image]

When you `single-click` a file in the left sidebar's file browser or open it from the quick open menu (<kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd>, type the file name, <kbd>Enter</kbd>), Visual Studio Code opens it in what's called "Preview Mode", which allows you to quickly view files.

**It's a feature, not a bug.**

- Very often while programming you will only need to open a file for a small window of time, to "preview" its contents.

[FOR MORE INFO](https://vscode.one/new-tab-vscode/)

Answer (score 9):

enabling using GUI

go to `Code -> Preferences -> Settings -> User -> Window -> New Window`

here **Open Files In New Window** under drop down list select "on" that's it.

my VS Code version 1.38.1

Comment: I was having an issue where "Go to definition..." was continually opening in same file window (was frustrating as would have to re-find my starting point). This seemed to fix things for me mostly (initial "Go to definition..." now opens in new file window).

Comment: This setting is as far as I'm aware about if new windows should be opened, not the permanence of tabs.

Answer (score 8):

As hktang above indicates:

one **Click** opens the file in preview mode (header text in italics)

**Double click** the same file, it goes out of preview-mode (header text changes from italic to normal font)

I think this is a "compromise" feature allowing users,  to "navigate" both worlds; preview and none-preview.

- All you do is click the file to open it in the right panel.
- Then immediately double click it to keep it there.
- Or - just treble click. File opens in none preview mode.

Answer (score 7):

You need to edit `settings.json` file, which is located at:

```
Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
macOS $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

{
  "workbench.editor.showTabs": true,
  "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- Go to `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings`
- Search for `workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen`
- Set it to false or uncheck it.

Answer (score 4):

For those who using Windows OS:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Select `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` from the list
- Select all and Paste this
  `{ "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false }`

That's it now it will open in a new tab instead of replacing on the existing one.

For reference look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

to open another file in a new tab keeping the current file open,

- first **double click** (left click) the **current file**
- then **click** (single click) the **new file**

in this way, the new file will be opened in another tab

#OR

you can **drag the new file** from vs code project explorer and **drop** it beside opened tab, exactly where the new tab will be opened

Answer (score 3):

Actually, VSCode shows you the preview of a file when you open it. If you want to open files in a new tab, just disable the preview with this setting (paste this in the settings.json file).

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
```

— you can take it one step further and use this setting

```
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
```

— It will open your VSCode editor with a blank new untitled file to quickly get started.

Answer (score 3):

Simple and Best way is whenever you open new file it is in preview mode  so simply press the **CTRL** + **K** and  then press **ENTER** then you done with preview mode , Now this file will remain always open until you closed it that's what you need to do ....

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is, instead of making changes in settings of vscode, whenever you open a file through a reference,you will see that the file is in preview mode(the name of file is in italic) and in the sidebar you will see that same preview file in focus just double tap it and it will be pinned on the tab,so that it wont get replaced by another file in preview mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is so confusing. All developers I asked didn't appreciate this default behavior.

I use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open project files.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I also had to set `workbench.editor.showTabs` property to true (in addition to `workbench.editor.enablePreview`)

I'm not sure how it got changed to false. Maybe, I've accidentally set it to false using some shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

for me, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> did the trick.

Comment: As soon as you do anything to edit the file, including pressing Shift-Enter, it exits preview mode. @gandalf Saxe's answer - open the file by pressing Right-Arrow so it opens properly, and not in Preview is more effective

Comment: it's not the Shift + Enter, the exit from preview mode occurred because you edited the file by pressing Enter and putting a new line. it's only the Enter

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Workbench -> Editor Management -> Enable Preview

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had accidentally changed the setting for viewing files in tabs and didn't know where to look to change back to the behavior I was used to i.e. double clicking on the files name in the file explorer pane (typically LHS) to open the file in a new tab.

There is a setting to check or uncheck "enable tabs".

In VS Code 1.77.3 you can click on the 3 dots on the RHS (see image below)
[image]

Note:
**Full version info of my VS Code installation:**
Version: 1.77.3
Commit: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
Date: 2023-04-12T09:16:52.732Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.2.0-20-generic snap
Sandboxed: Yes

Answer (score 1):

Tried all above answers but below one worked finally. Put that in `setting.json`.

```
"workbench.editor.showTabs": true,
```

Comment: For me worked "window.restoreWindows" then selected "Preserve". Now if the editor is closed and I double click a file ( to open it ), the editor will open all the previous files that were left opened in the last use of the editor + the new file I've just doubled clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the **settings.json**

```
{
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have opened a file in preview mode and want to open new file in another tab:
For Mac: use `cmd` + `p` -> find the file and `alt` + `enter`.

Comment: Hi,
The question here is about opening a file from explorer menu, not by searching out the file via `cmd+P` option. Moreover, anyhow, the `cmd+P` option opens a file in a new tab itself.
But your method definitely works!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to additionally disable the `Editor > Limit` option to work correctly with the above settings mentioned in the comments. Otherwise, it will keep re-use the same tabs [image]

Answer (score 0):

File > Preferences does not exist in VS2022

For VS 2022 specifically, this does work: open the menu Tools > Options > expand Environment > select Tabs and Windows

Then, simply uncheck "Allow new files to be opened in the preview tab"

Checked was my default. Changing it to unchecked got rid of the preview tabs in VS 2022

Answer (score 0):

For Version: 1.85.1 follow the instruction

[image: For Version: 1.85.1 follow the instruction]