# Keyboard shortcut to take file out of preview mode in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

If I quick open a file using the quick open menu, is there a **keyboard shortcut** that will take the opened file outside of preview mode so that when I open a new file it won't replace the currently open one?

(I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut as opposed to double-clicking the filename or tab in order to keep my workflow keyboard oriented)

Comment: Note that after hitting control-p (Quick Open), you can hit the right arrow key instead of enter to make a file open not-in-preview-mode. Although then you have to hit escape to close the list of files (I wish there was a way to avoid that).

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try the `View: Keep Editor` command (default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

[image]

Note: this shortcut is a *chord*, meaning that <kbd>Enter</kbd> must be pressed after releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: Try ⌘+K, Enter on Mac.

Answer (score 23):

As of v1.19 (released in December 2017) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> opens the file (after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) **NOT** in preview mode but in a "permanent", touched status.

Related question: [How do I configure Visual Studio Code to open files always in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713405/how-to-config-vscode-to-open-files-always-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use press Right Arrow key, while the name of the file is highlighted.

Comment: For me, using Alt+Enter opens the file in side-by-side mode instead of creating a new tab. Using the Right Arrow key almost works but I have to hit Escape to close the list of files. Do you know any way to skip that extra keystroke?

Comment: **For anyone using the Vimium plugin:** the accepted answer collides with vim's keystrokes, but this answer works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 20):

If you would rather open the file directly from Quick Open (skipping the preview mode altogether), you can change this in the settings or add this to `settings.json`:

```json
"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false
```

If you want to disable previews for other means of opening files (like the project explorer), this will do the trick:

```json
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

Comment: This isn't working for me on macOS Catalina with the latest VS Code. Posted an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110952. Using Alt+Enter to open from CMD+P (in answer from Mark above, was the most elegant solution to this problem, IMO)