# vscode: Open file instead of previewing file from quick open

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When I open up the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), type in a filename and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the file will automatically be opened in *Preview* mode.

#### Open File Permanently

What I want is to have an option to open a file permanently from the Command Palette. I am aware of the `"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen"` settings, but that will *disable* Preview mode.

For example, selecting a file in the Command Palette and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will open the file as Preview in a new Split view. I am looking for a similar shortcut to open a file permanently.

## Edit 1

Correction: I meant the **Quick Look** mode using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. The *Command Palette* is used to run commands, and cannot search or open files.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945820/vs-code-keyboard-shortcut-to-take-file-out-of-preview-mode/47840585?noredirect=1#comment82645498_47840585

Comment: @Mark Which may in turn be a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713405/how-to-config-vscode-to-open-files-always-in-a-new-tab/38723094#38723094]).

Comment: This is not duplicate, because in the mentioned question, they ask to get the file out of preview mode. OP here asks to open it permanently, which are two different things.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just press the Right arrow when your file is highlighted.  The Command Palette stays exactly where it is and your file opens (in non-preview) in the background.  You can do this as many times as you like.

Comment: This seems to be a regression with the latest release.  Bug tracking the issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95076

Comment: This works again as of 1.44.2 (released 2020-04-16)

Answer (score 26):

What I was looking for was:  `Settings -> Workbench -> Editor Management`

I set `Enable Preview` and unset `Enable Preview from Quick Open` which makes VSCode behave like st3.

Answer (score 12):

With Quick Look open, select the file you wish to open permanently

[image: Quick open]

then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the file permanently.

Note: this shortcut only works in Visual Studio Code 1.19 and above

[@GunnerGuyven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47677500/399759) also work - select file in Quick Look then <kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: This is right, but it opens the file in split view and not in the same window as new tab.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017: Uncheck all checkboxes of menu Debug > Options, section Environment > Tabs and Windows > Preview Tab

[image]

Comment: @MaximilianoBecerra: Yeah, I know. But I came here searching it for VS, may be it will be useful later to one in the same situation as me.