# How to turn preview mode tab to normal mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I double click to open a file in a tab so it's in normal mode. And I use  <kbd>cmd</kbd> + click or <kbd>F12</kbd> on a word to look at the definition but the definition tab is opened in preview mode. When I want to look at another definition in this new tab it would overwrite this new tab. Any solution to convert a preview mode tab to normal mode when it's already open in a preview mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to config vscode to open files always in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713405/how-to-config-vscode-to-open-files-always-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: @HaaLeo I want to turn opened preview tab into normal tab but still want to keep preview feature. Sometimes preview feature still useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41460658/2469567), using keep open.

[image]