# How do I change a preview tab to be an open tab via a command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

After you open a file in preview mode, you get a tab with *italic* file name. How to change the tab to a permanent open (i.e., change from *italic* to normal) by command?

Just to clarify, the question is:

- I still want to keep preview mode enable in ctrl-p
- It is about change of mind after the file was opened in preview mode
- **I want to complete this action without any mouse movement**

Comment: @Mark That's asking a very different question.

Comment: It has all the answers, including yours below.

Comment: That shortcut was included as peripherally related information in *one* of the answers, as far as I can see.  That's not enough for the question to be a duplicate, in my opinion.

Comment: @jonsca, thanks. That's a different question. Mark, I have added some clarification to the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387057/how-to-turn-preview-mode-tab-to-normal-mode  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945820/vs-code-keyboard-shortcut-to-take-file-out-of-preview-mode. I stop looking after my first three search hits were spot on

Comment: @jonsca, you answer me question. Thanks.

Comment: The command is `View: Keep Editor` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945820/vs-code-keyboard-shortcut-to-take-file-out-of-preview-mode