# Why add missing import open new tab with the same file in vscode?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Hi I have an issue with my ide vscode from some time (like 2weeks ago it was all fine !) I searched but didnt found.

when im missing some import in vscode in my angular project but onlt in few components (not all ? ) 
When i chose 'add missing import' or 'add all missing imports'
instead of just adding it at the top - it opens new tab with the same file and added imports. 
what I did wrong ? I splited so you can see that from the top is still missing so red underline after clicked add all... but on bottom it is automaticly opened second tab of the same file and with imports.

please advice

i tryied reinstalling  / removing all extensiont / deleted config.[image]

thanks

### edit

the solution i figured out is rename modules to Modules folder... (does not known why )
or rename component - in this screen Module name was the same as component name.
also i does not known why this is issue for ide... ?

yep it is naming issue - in soem service now i have same issue, when it open in second tab it open same file but showing name of file starting from uppercase. if i changed this file name to Upercase first letter and it is fine - where search for issue ? could it be node.js some sase sensitive / insensitive settings ?
regards

Comment: check this answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713405/open-files-always-in-a-new-tab

Comment: nope this is not this issue

Comment: If there are any issues with the IDE or autocompletion it is probably most likely due to changes to the **tsconfig.json** file, at the root of your project folder. Here IDE options and complier options can be set. A good source can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

Comment: This probably won't help you much ... but try disabling your tslinter and any other extension you might have installed.This will help you narrow down the issue to plugin or vscode.

Comment: as i wrote i disabled / uninstalled all extensions , found a solution - updated 1st post but have no idea why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a bug in VS Code 1.38 related to path case. The file you have on top as a lowercase `modules` while the one below has an uppercase `Modules`

[The issue is tracked here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71990)

Comment: thanks i also was thinking about opening bug there but didnt found this one before