# Open files always in a new tab in Visual Studio Codespaces environment?

Tags: visual-studio-code, codespaces

When I open a file it will be opened and replaced by tab that is open at that moment. That's not what I want, because the file needs to be opened in a new tab.

I use Visual Studio Codespaces environment.

Comment: Did you try double clicking on the files when opening from the explorer?

Comment: Yeah, I just want this to happen with a single click. :)

Comment: related question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713405/open-files-always-in-a-new-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false` in your settings.json or you can go to the UI and disable these

[image: Workbench]