# Hover over filename in explorer to preview file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does VS Code allow for such a feature. I'd like to hold (say `Ctrl`) and then use my mouse to and hover over files and have them preview in the editor. Essentially this allows me to quickly explore the contents of a large number of files without taking the very long time of clicking each one to glance and their contents. This is especially important in some code structures where there are many many small files.

Comment: `without taking the very long time of clicking each one` One could argue it's not saving you any time if you have to press CTRL and hover it anyways. Too each their own though; we all have preferences. There is a built-in feature to preview files, by pressing space, or clicking one time, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38723094/2353523), but not with mouse hover.

Comment: Sometimes you just want to quickly glance at the content of the file without clicking it. THis is especially true in repos which a very large number of files where it becomes hard to tell what is in which.

Comment: I hear ya, and it’s a fair point, but the option to single-click requires less thought, I think; you don’t have to press another button, and it automatically reuses the same editor (plus your mouse is already there in that circumstance). Just offering you the options. I wouldn’t be surprised if there was an extension for this but there is no native support, including accessibility.