# How to get file paths for tabs in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Im working on a VSCode extension to get all paths to the files that are open in the editor.

Lets say I have these tabs open. One focused and another is not:

[image: open tabs]

Is there a way to get the file paths to each file?
A array of path strings for example.
I found a answer that gave me the path to files that are opened and "focused":
`var currentlyOpenTabfilePath = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.uri.fsPath;`
But how do I get the other paths?

Comment: I answered that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64611182/when-opening-multiple-files-in-vscode-only-the-first-is-actually-loaded-in-memo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workspace has all the required info:

```
    for (const document of workspace.textDocuments) {
            const theName = document.fileName;
...
        }
    }
```

Note: this works only for text documents. Others like webviews are not enumerated here (and they usually are not associated with an own file).

Comment: Also, it may be an issue or not, but documents can be opened (for editing, for example) but not shown - so not in a tab.  `workspace.textDocuments` will report opened documents, not shown documents.  Again, for the situation this may or may not be an issue, but one should be aware of this difference.