# How to open files in a new window in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I m trying to configure Visual Studio Code (VSC) so that when I click on a file in the Explorer, it opens in a new window while keeping the previous window open. By default, files open in the same window, but I want to change this behavior.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this in VSC?

Comment: When you say `window`, do you really mean editor tab?  If so, disable the setting `Workbench > Editor:  Enable Preview`.

Comment: in which case, this would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38713405/11107541