# How to quickly find files or symbols in a project in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here's a demonstration of the feature in IntelliJ (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtnI2doW6XE)?

In case the video isn't viewable, basically the user presses a key-combo, and a dialog box pops up that will reactively response and filter based on the string the user starts to type in. It will show classes and files (and much more) matching what you've typed in. I won't go in to all the details, as I'm not looking for an exact match to this functionality -- I'd be happy if it just searched based on file name for starters! Anything to prevent me from having to browse for a filename in the project Explorer to open the file in vs code when I want to switch to the given file.

I saw [How do I search for files in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095376/how-do-i-search-for-files-in-visual-studio-code) - for me (on Linux) `Ctrl-E` just shows the file I currently have open under the project explorer (useful sometimes, but not what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you just looking for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> That brings up a file list.  Which is searchable.  You can then tab down and right arrow opens up that file.  Enter will open a split editor on the file.

Also, if you <kbd>CTR</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> and then type <kbd>?</kbd> you will get a list of keys you can hit such as to "Go to Symbols" and much more in your file or workspace.

And look at <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> it probably does exactly what you are looking for as far as files go.

Comment: I found it - this particular keybinding had been changed for me by an extension  - the command name is `workbench.action.quickOpen`. After using the "Emacs Friendly Keymap" this became `Ctrl+x b`, which I should have realized as being only natural ... thanks. `Ctrl+x Ctrl+f` also worked with this emacs mode. Things are rather confusing though, as the latter does show up when I search keybindings, but the former does not.

Answer (score 35):

- <kbd>Cmd + P</kbd> opens a search bar for **files** ([doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_quick-file-navigation)),
- <kbd>Cmd + T</kbd> opens a search bar for **symbols** ([doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_open-symbol-by-name)),

Comment: In case you have your keybindings remapped like me, you can find the shortcuts by typing (respectively) `> go to file` and `> go to symbol in workspace` into the search bar.

Answer (score 5):

The command is called `Go to Symbol in Workspace`. On my machine, it's assigned to <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd> key.
You can also just press <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> and type <kbd>#</kbd> followed by symbol name to search for the symbol.