# How to, inside Visual Studio Code, to search for files with a certain extension containing a certain text

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know that it is possible to search files by their contents by clicking at the hourglass on the left side; I also know that it is possible to [search for files by their name by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30108348/679240).

The problem is: I need to do both. I need to, for example, search for some specific text, but only inside '*.ts' files.

Is there a way to do this inside Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a button under regex in global search: `"Toggle Search Details"` (ellipsis)

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's weird how this fails to appear in a Google search... :P