# vscode - how to get file search (not content) to include (git-) ignored files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Although this is not a direct dev question, but it does relate to a dev tool, which is very related to my development work:

When I search for a file in VSCode (CTRL+P), I see that it doesn't include files and folders that are a part of the .gitignore file.

I can very well see the logic in that, and that's fine, but how can I disable this (default?) behavior? Meaning, I do want this search to include ALL files in the project, regardless to the .gitignore file (or any other ignore file, for that matter).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Open visual studio code settings (`cmd`+ `,` on Mac or `Ctrl`+`,`), search for the setting:

`Search: Use Ignore Files`

and untick the checkbox

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this for a single search? As in, don't use the setting to control whether .gitignore'd files are ignored, just prefix the search with something like `all . . .`. I realize this is a longshot.

Comment: You can toggle the "Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files" when performing a search: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/323878/35752446-e01ea914-0810-11e8-8d1e-9877a751c5ca.png

Comment: Don't know why it doesn't work for all those mentioned under `.gitignore` for me.

Comment: is there a way to include a certain directory while ignoring all other files

Comment: @gbalduzzi Luckily, this also affects `Ctrl-p`/`Ctrl-e` search. Where there're no any tweakable controls.

Comment: There will be too many noise to untick the option. Use `.ignore` to negate specific files.

Comment: @Onkeltem No matter what I set the toggle to as per gbaduzzi's comment, the ctrl-p (on mac) search doesn't include the excluded files.

Comment: This setting (and even its description) is honestly a bit vague. What should I set to result in which outcome? Just to confirm, "use ignore files" mean that VSCode uses the ignore file in order to specifically NOT search among those files, or does "use" mean that it WILL use the list of files to additionally search among them somehow?

Answer (score 35):

As the screenshot in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55949239/667158) shows, vscode uses rules in both `.gitignore` and `.ignore`. Since Git only recognizes `.gitignore`, we can negate some rules in `.ignore` to bring them back in the vscode search result.

A demo:

.gitignore

```
.env.local
```

.ignore

```
!.env.local
```

This trick also works for tools like `rg` and `fd`.

Comment: This was the only way I found to get the ctrl-p (cmd-p) search to include git-ignored files. Thank you

Comment: This is clever!!

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if this was still useful but one way I found out is. There was a `search.exclude` setting in the config option

Nornally we would use it to exclude pattern by set it to true. However, we could force the inclusion of excluded pattern by setting the rule as false

```json
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.asset":true,
        "**/*.mat":true,
        "**/*.meta":true,
        "**/*.prefab":true,
        "**/*.unity":true,
    },
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/*.asset":false,
        "**/*.mat":false,
        "**/*.meta":false,
        "**/*.prefab":false,
        "**/*.unity":false,
    }
}
```

This is my setting for unity project and this was made all the meta files that was ignored missing from explorer. But I still be able to searching its content

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that your working directory is an actual Git repository.

VSCode doesn’t skip paths from `.gitignore` if you didn’t perform `git init` or `git clone` in the first place.

Comment: This answer is false, VS Code does use `.gitignore` to ignore files unless you have those files already open in tabs.