# VS Code file search fails to find files sometimes

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code sometimes is not able to find files (via file search triggered with CTRL+P) that are located outside of src folder in project. It does find them if they were used recently, but not otherwise. Also sometimes finds other files that are in the same location as the sought file, but not the ones I was looking for. Eg. if I search for `.env` (which is located in main folder), a file called `.env.sample` is found, but `.env` is not - although they are located in the same folder.

What might be causing this strange behavior?

Comment: Do you happen to have a large folder (like node_modules) in your project directory?

Comment: @DorinBotan Yes, I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check your `.gitignore`. VSCode will exclude files in `.gitignore` from QuickSearch.

If that's not the source of your problems, make sure VSCode is searching in the right place, and not searching where it shouldn't.
There is a default exclude setting for both Search and QuickSearch (Ctrl + P) which looks like the one below. You can check your own with `>Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)`.

```
"search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true,
    "**/*.code-search": true
},
```

It is possible to override these in the Search tab using the **files to include** ...

[image]

... or globally (which will enable it for QuickSearch too), in your user settings.json (`>Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`) with:

```
"search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles": false,
"search.useParentIgnoreFiles": false,
"search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": false,
    "**/bower_components": false,
    "**/*.code-search": false
}
```

Note, some directories are excluded by default because searching through them is quite slow. Therefore, if you have a large directory that VSCode searches through, it's better to exclude it from the search.

Comment: Thank you, I disregarded the fact that I had some private patterns in `.git exclude` apart from the `.gitignore` from the repo. Is it possible to override somehow through the settings the search exclusion for files search?

Comment: @Eggon I found an old answer on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949132/vscode-how-to-get-file-search-not-content-to-include-git-ignored-files