# How to search the entire Flutter source code in android studio or vscode

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

in Android Studio, we can search in the project with "ctrl+shift+f"(in Windows),

but that just shows search results only within our own project.

How can we search any class or method **in the entire Flutter source code?**

(for example, if I want to search the `BackdropFilter` class in the Flutter source code,
what should I do?)

We can use *'go to definition'* in the IDE, but I just want to search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30108348/9455325

Comment: Thanks @rickimaru, but I think that answer is about searching for a 'file name', not some strings *in* the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do these steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open the search window
2. On **Directory** tab, choose the destination of your Flutter directory. In my case, it's `C:\src\flutter` (on Window)
3. Type in your widget name. Voila!

[image]