# vs code explorer filter how to limit to contiguous strings

Tags: visual-studio-code, filtering

in VS code, I wand to use the filename filter to find files with the string "opus" in them (case insensitive).  However it matches all files with any of the letters o, p, u, s as here:
[image]

how can I limit the filter to whole strings?

Comment: I have never been able to get this filename filter to start anytime

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75011220/836330 and using Ctrl+F find in the Explorer.