# How to get a list of all files matching search criteria in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As per the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095376/how-do-i-search-for-files-in-visual-studio-code), there are two primary ways to search for files in VSCode:

1. By using `CTRL/CMD + P/E` to search and "go to file"
2. By clicking anywhere in the explorer tree and typing

**Why do the above solutions not suit my needs?**

I need a way to search for files and get a full list of them (in plain view) so I can easily scan them.

The 1st method returns only partial results unless I scroll down.

The 2nd method only searches the folder tree that's currently open.

---

I know I can use the `find` command in Linux to achieve this, but can I achieve something similar in the editor itself?